# register a user in converse.js to ejabberd server using javascript

Tags: ejabberd, converse.js

how to register an user using converse.js to ejabberd from javascript instead of using register form of converse.js. I want to register the user using converse.js api instead doing it manually from the form. Please help me with your suggestions.

Comment: You can always use inband registration XMPP specification directly to create a user.

Comment: can you be more specific what do mean by inband registration. How do achieve it through converse.js

Comment: XEP-0077: Inband Registration. See: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html

Comment: i had went through blog , i am not able make out how to achieve it. I quite new ejabberd and converse so, how to please bit explain how to achieve it

Comment: This is not blog but XMPP specification for registration. I think if you not familiar with XMPP, "Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery" is a good book that will be really helpful.

Comment: thnks i will certainly look into it

Comment: function onConnect(status) {
  if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED)connection.connect('someuser@Vostro-3558-PC','somepassword',onConnect);
    connection.addHandler(registerCreds, 'jabber:iq:register', 'iq', null, 'reg1', null);
  } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
    if(!REGISTERED) { register();}connection.addHandler(registerCreds, 'jabber:iq:register', 'iq', null,'reg1', null);
    connection.addHandler(acknowledgeCreds, 'jabber:iq:register', 'iq', null, 'reg2', null);
    $().mousemove(function(e){sendMessageToListener(e.pageX, e.pageY);
      })}}

Comment: the above code i trying to connect to ejabberd server through a websocket url. the status always comes up as connecting. I not getting a work through for this

Comment: function registerCreds(msg) {
    var iq = $iq(
                 {
                     "id": 'reg1',
                     "type": "result"
                 })
     .c("query", { "xmlns": "jabber:iq:register" })
     .c('username').t('*********')
     .up()
     .c('password').t('****');
  connection.send(iq);
  return true;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converse.js supports [XMPP-0077 in band registrations](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html) to allow users to manually register new accounts for themselves.

It should be possible to also do the same thing automatically/programmatically instead of expecting the user to do it.

However, you would need to write new code to do this.

Instead of letting the user specify their username and password, you would generate and then send those values to the XMPP server automatically with Javascript.

However, a better and more secure way would most likely be to do this server-side. Either by using a RESTful API provided by the XMPP server (some do, but not all), or by creating a server-side XMPP client which does the registration.

Comment: i used strophe.register.js to register band registrations

Comment: Oh yes, I should have mentioned Strophe.js and its plugins